# PHP 'is_dir' in combination with 'urldecode' is false, same with string value is true?

Tags: php, character-encoding, filesystems

I have a weird problem. On my development server all stuff works but on the live server it doesn't. I have a folder with a special char like "ö" in it. On the development server i do this to check if the filename is a directory ($dir = "coördinatie"):

```
 if (is_dir(urldecode($dir)))
  echo "true";
 else {
  echo "false";
 }
```

The result is true. On the live server the result is false. The weird thing is... a hardcoded string works fine and the result is true. Like this:

```
 if (is_dir("coördinatie"))
  echo "true";
 else {
  echo "false";
 }
```

I tried typecasting to string and such but i can't figure it out. Hope someone has a clue.

Comment: Check the encoding of the files you have the hardencoding in (the PHP source file defining the string) and tell us please about the encoding used for the file-systems on both the development server and the live server. **Are both environments identically configured?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be this:

`urldecode` generally decodes to UTF-8.
Your hardcoded string may be in Latin-1, since the source code is saved as such.
The file system (functions) on your local machine like Unicode, the ones on production like Latin-1.

You may have to convert the string into an encoding that your file system expects.
You can confirm my suspicion by comparing the values of `bin2hex` for both strings.

Comment: `urldecode` is a binary safe function in PHP and it is encoding agnostic and always decodes into binary 8 bit as one octet - not specifically UTF-8.

Comment: @hakre True, should have said that URL encoded values are typically UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: The bin2hex values for string and hardcoded values differ indeed: 

4943542d436ff67264696e61746f72
4943542d436fc3b67264696e61746f72

I really have no clue how to convert the string in the right way and don't know how to look for the file systems encoding.

Comment: i found it and used: iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", urldecode($dir)); to convert my string and all's fine now. Thanks for the help.